# is this piece of haskell code correct, if so why?

Tags: haskell

the haskell wiki (here : https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad ) says the state monad bind operator is defined like this :

```
(>>=) :: State s a -> (a -> State s b) -> State s b
(act1 >>= fact2) s = runState act2 is 
    where (iv,is) = runState act1 s
          act2 = fact2 iv
```

however it seems incorrect to me as the result of the bind operator is a function wrapped in a constructor thus cannot be applied (I'm talking about this pattern : `(act1 >>= fact2) s`)

Comment: In fact a `State` does *not* contain the state, it basically encapsulates the *change* of a state. When you create such `State` objects, you typically "chain" several state changes, and eventually you call `runState` with the initial state.

Comment: That does look wrong to me, for the reason you gave. I just checked the link and don't see that snippet anywhere though? [Edit: found it. It's probably a mistake, it is a wiki after all]

Comment: @RobinZigmond: it is probably located at Wikipedia: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State

Comment: It looks indeed something is wrong,  unless `State` is just a type synonym of an arrow (like `type State s a = s -> (a, s)`), but if we use a `newtype`, then indeed it is not completely correc.t

Answer (score 7):

**In short:** A `State` object itself does *not* encapsulate the state, it encapsulates the *change* of a state.

Indeed, the `State` type is defined as:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

where `runState` is thus a function that takes a state `s`, and returns a result `a` and a new state.

The bind operator `(>>=) :: State s a -> (a -> State s b) -> State s b` basically "chains" state changes together. It thus takes one state changing function `f1 :: s -> (a, s)`, and a function `f2 :: a -> State s b`, and thus creates a function `g :: s -> (b, s)` so to speak that is encapsulated in a `State` constructor. The second function `f2` thus takes an `a` and returns such state changing function as well.

So the bind operator can be defined as:

```
(State f1) >>= f2 = State $ \i -> let (y, s) = f1 i in runState (f2 y) s
```

Here we have `i` as initial state, and we thus will first "chain" `i` through the `f1` state changer. This returns then a 2-tuple: `y` is the "result" of that call, and `s` is the new state, we will then pass the result and the new state to `f2`. Note that here we do *not* make state changes at all, we only construct a `State` object that *can* do that. We thus postpone the real chaining.

If the `State` is however defined as above, then the piece of code does not match that definition, it defines it, like [@HTWN says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54732806/is-this-piece-of-haskell-code-correct-if-so-why/54732978#comment96255084_54732978), as:

```
type State s a = s -> (a, s)
```

In that case, it is correct, given that `runState` is then the `id` function, since then:

```
(>>=) :: State s a -> (a -> State s b) -> State s b
(>>=) act1 fact2 = f
    where f s = act2 is 
              where (iv,is) = act1 s
                    act2 = fact2 iv
```

In order to make it compatible with our `State` type, we thus add some logic to unwrap and wrap it in the `State` data constructor:

```
(>>=) :: State s a -> (a -> State s b) -> State s b
(>>=) act1 fact2 = State f
    where f s = runState act2 is 
              where (iv,is) = runState act1 s
                    act2 = fact2 iv
```

then it is indeed correct. The main error is not wrapping it in a `State` data constructor.

Comment: The Wiki page seems to be using the simplification `type State s a = s -> (a, s)`, instead of a `newtype`. The `(>>=)` then defined is not actually part of the `Monad` class, just a free-floating function, which is where the irregularity comes from. I think this answer would be better if, instead of declaring the page wrong (or, "not entirely correct"), it just pointed out this fact, and offered the "correct" version as how it's actually implemented, with `State` actually becoming an instance of `Monad`.